# Write to existing text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a SignUpForm. When the program is started it creates new file where will write Username on one side and passwords on other side. Here's what I made so far, but it ain't writing over and over again. Please help. Thanks!

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.File

Public Class SignUpForm

    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim fileMembers As New System.IO.StreamWriter("Members.txt")

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            TextBox2.PasswordChar = ""
            TextBox3.PasswordChar = ""
        Else
            TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*"
            TextBox3.PasswordChar = "*"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TextBox2.Text = TextBox3.Text And TextBox4.Text = recaptcha.Text Then
            test()
            MsgBox("Passwords Match, Logged It!")
            Me.Close()
        End If
        If TextBox2.Text <> TextBox3.Text Then
            MsgBox("Passwords Do Not Match")
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
        End If
        If TextBox4.Text <> recaptcha.Text Then
            MsgBox("The verification code isn't valid")
            TextBox4.Text = ""
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub SignUpForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cnt = 0
        g = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Main()
        fileMembers.WriteLine("Username" + " : " + "Password")
        fileMembers.WriteLine("===================")
        fileMembers.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub test()
        If Not File.Exists("Members.txt") Then
            Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("Members.txt")
                sw.WriteLine("")
            End Using
        End If

        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("Members.txt")
            sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text + " : " + TextBox2.Text)
        End Using

        Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("Members.txt")
            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
            Loop
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Label4.Text = Str(cnt)
    End Sub

End Class
```

(My problem is, after the log-in is successful, it should write the username and password and then close the program. The program ether closes and doesn't write or gives an error saying can't access the file because it is in use)

Comment: Post relevant code here, not on other sites.

Comment: Have you tried running the program in debug mode going line by line? At what point exactly do things not work?

Comment: The program works just fine, but when the login is successful, it doesn't write the username and password to the .txt file (but it should)

Comment: When your class is initialised, you are creating a StreamWriter for Members.txt called fileMembers and you never close it. That would explain why Members.txt is in use when you try to crreate another StreamWriter for it in the Test Sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please note - never write a login and password to a file on a PC or whatever.

Nevertheless I did a quick and dirty coding for your problem. So please read the code and try to learn from there. Of course many other solutions are possible. You have to clean your code e.g. 'TextBox2' => Pwd , 'TextBox3' => PwdRepeated for better reading. Happy coding ...

[image]

[image]

Give it a try ...

```
   Imports System.IO
   Imports System.IO.File


   Public Class Form1

     Dim cnt As Integer
     Dim g As Integer

     Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
       If CheckBox1.Checked Then
         TextBox2.PasswordChar = ""
         TextBox3.PasswordChar = ""
       Else
         TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*"
         TextBox3.PasswordChar = "*"
       End If
     End Sub

     Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       If TextBox2.Text = TextBox3.Text And TextBox4.Text = lblrecaptcha.Text Then
         test()
         MsgBox("Passwords Match, Logged It!")
         Me.Close()
       End If
       If TextBox2.Text <> TextBox3.Text Then
         MsgBox("Passwords Do Not Match")
         TextBox2.Text = ""
         TextBox3.Text = ""
       End If
       If TextBox4.Text <> lblrecaptcha.Text Then
         MsgBox("The verification code isn't valid")
         TextBox4.Text = ""
       End If

     End Sub

     Private Sub SignUpForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       cnt = 0
       g = 1

       '--- open or create the file ----------
       Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "members.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
       Dim s As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
       s.WriteLine("Username" + " : " + "Password")
       s.WriteLine("===================")
       s.Close()
       s.Close()
       fs.Close()

       cnt = cnt + 1
       Label4.Text = "DE-" + Trim(Str(cnt))
       lblrecaptcha.Text = "DE-" + Trim(Str(cnt))

     End Sub

     Private Sub test()
       '--- log it ----------
       Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "members.txt"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
       Dim s1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs1)


       s1.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text + " : " + TextBox2.Text)
       s1.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + TextBox1.Text + " : " + TextBox2.Text)
       s1.Close()
       fs1.Close()

       Dim sOut As String
       sOut = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("Members.txt")
       Console.WriteLine(sOut)
     End Sub

   End Class
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping :) I fixed it